# How to use MouseWheel in NotifyIcon

Tags: c#, mousewheel, notifyicon

I'm building a tiny program for controlling master volume with the following requirements

1. Sits in the Task Bar (next to the clock)
2. On single click it will Mute/Unmute the master volume
3. While the mouse is hovering over the icon the mouse wheel controls volume Up/Increase Down/Decrease.

I have got the first two working so far by combining these two projects http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/290013/Formless-System-Tray-Application
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18520/Vista-Core-Audio-API-Master-Volume-Control

The trouble I'm having is with no.3 which I'm guessing is the most complicated part of my tiny program.

Error: 'System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon' does not contain a definition for 'MouseWheel'

I'm running Windows 8.1 x64 .NET 4.5 / Visual Studio Express 2013

*Personal Background*

1. I am not a programmer.
2. I did do basic java in a computer course more than a decade ago.
3. I'm teaching myself C# from microsoftvirtualacademy.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens, because NotifyIcon is not a control, but a component (it's derived from Component class). MouseWheel event is a member of Control class, not Component.
So, NotifyIcon doesn't have MouseWheel event.

I'm afraid, there is no official solution for this problem, as public API (Shell_NotifyIcon) doesn't expose wheel information.

**UPD:** As requirements changed, there is my step-by-step guide

First, you need to add MouseClick handler for your NotifyIcon

```
notifyIcon.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(notifyIcon_MouseDown);
```

Then, add this event handler to your code-behind

```
void notifyIcon_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        // Increase volume here
    }
    else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        // Decrease volume here
    }
    else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Middle)
    {
        // Mute here
    }
}
```

Comment: if that be the case, i suppose i'll have to change my requirements, something like; volume increase as the left click is pressed, decrease for right, and mute for middle.

Comment: thank you, implementing it now. will still leave my question open a while longer, if there are no other suitable responses yours will be accepted.